# Compiler matching string to regex, using NFA

Tags: regex, compiler-construction, lexical-analysis

I was reading about compilers, the chapter about lexical analyzers(scanners) and I'm puzzled by the following statement:

*For an input string X and a regular expression R, the complexity for finding a match using non-deterministic finite automata is:*

```
O(len R * len X)
```

How can the complexity be polynomial in `len R`?
I'm under the impression that it depends exponentially on `len R`, because whenever we have a character which may appear a variable number of times(ie followed by the `*` symbol), we must test all possible number of occurences. If we have multiple characters which appear a variable number of times, we must check all possibilities(by backtracking).

Where am I wrong?

Comment: Maybe it talks about space complexity? Where exactly did you read this?

Comment: You don't have to 'test all possible number of occurrences'. You only have to continue consuming X while the same character recurs, which is linear in X, and if you have that recurring character you can't have any other recurring character at the same time, so there is no explosion.

Comment: @EJP: Think about `a*a`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> we must check all possibilities(by backtracking).

Not necessarily by backtracking. [There are many ways to implement an NFA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nondeterministic_finite_automaton#Implementation). By moving through the input linearly, and transitioning to multiple states at the same time (storing the set of active states in an `O(1)`-lookup structure), you will get exactly the mentioned runtime - number of states in NFA is linear to length of regex.

See also the popular articel [*Regular Expression Matching Can Be Simple And Fast*](http://swtch.com/~rsc/regexp/regexp1.html).